# How to convert Json Array (nested) in multiple rows

Tags: talend

I have a Json array that looks like this screenshot:

[image: JsonOutput]

Now I want to convert this array into a table format like this:

[image: tableOutput]

Currently I'm working with tExtractJSONFields. But I only find a way to target one of the nested array at the same time.

My expression:

```
"['book'][0].['category']"
    "['book'][0].['author']" 
        ......
```

So I got the Ouput for the first row. But I don't want to do the same for 50, 100 etc. rows.

Does anybody know a way to solve that?

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete [PrettyK's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47322721) answers, you could also use the tExtractJsonFields with the JsonPath option from the dropdown list.

In your input row, you would have something like "book" of type Object or String.
Then, in the component, you define all your fields (category, author, ..), and in the component, you just have to define :

1. The json field on which you will loop (here : book)
2. To link your field, you just then write "@.author" for example.

For more info on the JsonPath, there is this good [site](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

Answer (score 2):

In tExtractJsonFields, select edit Schema and give all the possible column you have in output schema. Select "Read by" as "Xpath".

Now in "Loop Xpath Query" write  "/book"

In the "Mapping" section, you will see all the output column under "Column" as you have given in Schema. Under Xpath Query put the respective column like :

if column is Author than Xpath Query would be "Author"

column is Price than Xpath Query would be "Price" and so on.

hope this help..